# herbs / teas for sleep and side effects of melatonin and dipenhydramine?

Tags: supplements, sleep, relaxation

what are some herbs / teas for sleep  and what are side effects of melatonin and dipenhydramine taken long term?

Please stop closing my questions there isn't really a nutrition/supplements stackexchange  and I don't want to book a doctors appointment to ask about this?

Comment: I'm sorry but unless your question is about exercise, or directly related to it, it continues to fall outside the scope of the site. Don't seek medical advice on the Internet! Sleep problems can have severe effects on your overall health, and you *should* book a doctor's appointment for it.

Comment: Most SEs have a relatively tough quality control to ensure that the questions decided to be on topic are answered most appropriately. This is really not the place to get anecdotal medical advice. It's your health you are risking by trusting strangers on the net, so do whatever you want, but instead of asking here, why don't you use one of those communities that do allow for people to write anything they like?

Comment: I mean ideally they have a reasonable source with some reliable studies such as 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrYc0-NSZZg&t=166s   
or idk it's widely used for long enough to be of some merit I'm not sure where else to post this kind of question actually